# When to use start and stop from SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, progress-bar, signalr, signalr.client

I've a MVC web application which has an Upload page to upload a file to the server and process the file. Because the processing can take some time (10 to 30 minutes) I use a progressbar to display the % complete.

On this page I've the following code to initialize SignalR:

```
// Define functions to facilitate push from the server.
m_uploadHub = $.connection.importDataHub;

$.extend(m_uploadHub.client, {
    updateProgress: function (pct) {
        progressbar.progressbar("value", pct);
    },

    updateStatus: function (status) {
        $("#status").html(status);
    },

    updateProgressBarText: function (text) {
        progressLabel.text(text);
    },

    complete: function () {
        // no
    }
});

try {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // Set connection id to hidden field
        $('#SignalRConnectionId').val($.connection.hub.id);
    });
}
catch (e) {
    alert('SignalR hub start fail: ' + e);
}
```

This means that when the page is loaded, the javascript code above will run and SignalR will be started and never stopped.

Is this design correct, or should I use the **$.connection.hub.start()** only when the user clicks the upload button to actually upload a file ?
And should I stop the connection with **$.connection.hub.stop()** when the MVC action returns? (file was uploaded successfully or some errors/warnings are returned)

Please advice.

Comment: I dont know why you are using SignalR for this, it seems to be a bit of overkill. An uploader like plupload : http://www.plupload.com/ has progress functionality built it and is a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting and stopping SignalR connections can be utilized many ways.  However, I'd argue that it's much more common to start a SignalR connection immediately and never stop it.

In your case depending on "if" you want to use the SignalR connection before/after the upload has been clicked/completed you may want to take a different approach.

If you truly will not use the SignalR connection unless the user clicks upload you should only start it when the upload button is clicked.  If you will not use the SignalR connection after your upload has completed definitely stop it.  No need to keep the server occupied with it if you're not using it.

To address a slightly different issue (brought up by @Steve): If this upload piece is all you're using SignalR for in your application it's probably overkill.